# is Google.API.Translate.Language.GetEnums() broken?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-translate

I'm trying to use Google.API.Translate.Language.GetEnums() but it tells me that Google.API.Translate.Language doesn't contain a definition for GetEnums() even though intelisense tells me there it is.

I've another project where it works fine and even when I use the same dll, it tells me it doesnt contain GetEnums().

Here's my code:

foreach (Google.API.Translate.Language L in Google.API.Translate.Language.GetEnums())
            {
                cBoxLanguageSelection.Items.Add(L.Name);
            }

Comment: Could you link to the API documentation please? (There are lots of different clients for the Google Translate API. I'm not sure which one you're using.)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/
you need to download the GoogleTranslateAPI_0.4_alpha.zip

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're really trying to call `Enumeration<Language>.GetEnums()` (it's defined in `Enumeration<T>`). Calling it "via" `Language` should work, although it's not how I would personally do it. Try this, just to see if it works:

```
foreach (var language in Enumeration<Language>.GetEnums())
{
    cBoxLanguageSelection.Items.Add(language.Name);
}
```

(with appropriate `using` directives, of course).

Comment: Still doesnt work... 
Basically, if I try to access Google.API.Translate.Language.GetEnums(), it wont compile and the error says: "Google.API.Translate.Language does not contain a definition for 'GetEnums'"
What it's weird is that I've used this method before and also, intellisense finds it.

Comment: I think my project got corrupted, I created another project, same dll file and it works =D

Comment: Fixed it on the original project, check this out: Looks like (at least in my case) Google API's have issues when your "Target Framework" is set to ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" instead of ".Net Framework 4", that worked!!..